# Drop all row who has at lease one cell that contains only '-' in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

There are negative numbers and some cells only contains `-`. They're there when the data is being imported. How can I drop them from the data-frame? Basically this is a notation of missing value.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you have a df

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[2,2,2,2,2,2,2], what=["what","what","what","-","what","-","what"]))
```

Then use

```
df[df.what.str.contains("-") == False]
```

output

```
    A  what
0  2  what
1  2  what
2  2  what
4  2  what
6  2  what
```

Comment: They want to drop "cells" that *only* contain `'_'`, so not something like "what-the-heck"

Comment: Also, `df.what.str.contains("-") == False` probably just be `~df.what.str.contains("-")`

Comment: From what I understand,  he wants to remove the cell that contains '-'. Anyway, as what you said if he wants the other way, df[df.what.str.contains("-") == True] will keep the cell that contains '-'

Comment: Just `df.what.str.contains("-")`, you don't need `df.what.str.contains("-") == True`

Comment: This only works for one colum but I have may columns